# Google App Engine not installing on IDE Netbean 7.1?

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans-7

When I try to install [google app engine plugin on Netbean IDE 7.1](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/Latest_NetBeans68/updates.xml) it gives me error like as follows

> Some plugins require plugin Java Hints to be installed. The plugin Java Hints is requested in implementation version 4. The following plugin is affected:
>
> Google App Engine Editor Hints

Comment: Try to find a plugin named "Java Hints"

Comment: @batbaatar there is no plugin listed as "Java Hints"

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problems. I tried to use NetBeans67 instead. http://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/1.0_NetBeans671/updates.xml
It works fine so far in Netbeans 7.0.1.